# JS alerts on leaving SP?

Tags: 2010, web-application, hyperlink, integration, intranet

We're going to include links to non-SP web applications in our corporate intranet. For those resources, I'd like to pop up an interstitial dialog/alert to make it obvious to the user that site navigation/authentication is changing and that they will need to use the back button to return.

Two thoughts I had-

I could just add JS popups to those links by hand. That's probably more than I want to ask a typical SP user to do. An admin would have to do that for them.

I could wrap the outside site in a frame, but then I'd have to validate that all of the features of the app worked in that configuration.

Is there any sort of feature that could give me this functionality globally for all links on the SP site?

Comment: Maybe this requirement comes from others, but this will be incredibly annoying for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use jQuery to inject the dialog to every external link. Add jQuery and the following script to .master page, something like:

```
$("a:not([href^='http://current.sharepointsite.com'])").click(function(){
    alert("You're about to leave SharePoint");
});
```

Or use some ready made jQuery plugin [here](http://rewdy.com/projects/view/leavenotice/).

Comment: The code above will make *any* hyperlink that uses http throw an alert.  That *includes* any OOTB quick launch or top nav links.

Comment: Yep, it was just a rough example, now modified to work better.